# Limiting WCF Data Members in Linq to SQL's DBML Serialization?

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql

I understand that you can set the **Serialization Mode = Unidirectional** to allow data contracts to your dbml auto-generated entities.  However, is there a way to *only* expose certain entities and ALSO limit the entities exposed to *only* expose certain properties of that entity as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Googled and found it so I'm posting here for prosperity's sake:

Credit:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/11/27/linq-to-sql-enabling-dbml-file-for-wcf.aspx

Basically you just set the DBML's **Serializable Mode = Unidirectional** and then you set the "Access" for each entity you don't want exposed to the Service equal to Friend instead of Public.  **Access = Friend**